# why $\frac{d}{dt}U(\gamma(t))=\langle \nabla_U(\gamma(t)),\gamma'(t)\rangle$?

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives

I do not understand why $\frac{d}{dt}U(\gamma(t))=\langle \nabla_U(\gamma(t)),\gamma'(t)\rangle$ where $U:\mathbb{R^2}\rightarrow\mathbb{R^2}$ and $\gamma:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R^2}$ are $c^{\infty }$ functions.

Should not the LHS be a vector while the RHS a number/scalar?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\nabla_U (\gamma(t))$ makes little to no sense as $U$ is a vector field. The $\nabla$-notation is more common for scalar fields $f: \mathbb{R}^N \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$. You should write $DU$ instead, where $(DU(x))_{ij} = \partial_j U_i(x)$ for $i, j \in \lbrace 1, 2 \rbrace$. Then
$$
\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}t} U(\gamma(t)) = DU(\gamma(t))\gamma'(t)
$$
according to the chain rule. Since we are using matrix-vector multiplication, both the LHS and the RHS are $\mathbb{R}^2$ vectors.